# Does council opinion matter?

Tags: crusader-kings-2

The Council tab also shows the opinion your Council members have of you. Does this have any effect whatsoever on their abilities or other things?

Does hiring loyal people as Council members have any positive impact? Or should you always go for the ones with the best skill, even if they dislike you?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

It generally has no effect - they all perform their jobs without any penalty.

However, they do count as being in your court, and so get a bonus to plot power against you (and disliking you, they are quite likely to join in plots against you). Furthermore, your spymaster gets a massive bonus to plot power against you as well. Definitely don't let someone who hates you become your spymaster.